# Can I select a number within my account to retrieve voice messages [PHP]

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

Getting the SID's for voicemails is pretty simple using PHP.  However, if I have phone multiple numbers in my account, how do I call the API for just the messages left to a specific number??

Answer (score 1):

You can't filter voice recordings by number I'm afraid but you've got a couple of other options:

- Get them by **call sid** if you know the call: `GET https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls/{CallSid}/Recordings.json` (combine with [getting all the calls for a specific number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-read-multiple-call-resources-and-filter-by-call-status-and-phone-number&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x): `GET https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls.json?To=%2B1234567890`)
- Get them by **conference sid** if you know the conference: `GET https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Conferences/{ConferenceSid}/Recordings.json`
- Get all voice recordings of the **account**: `GET https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Recordings.json`
- **Filter** by date created, e.g.: `GET https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Recordings.json?DateCreated%3C=2021-03-30T00%3A00%3A00Z&DateCreated%3E=2021-04-01T00%3A00%3A00Z` (all voice recordings from 30th and 31st of March 2021)

More info can be found in the [Twilio doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording?code-sample=code-get-all-recordings-for-an-account&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x#read-multiple-recording-resources).